# mongodb is not inserting big integer correctly (tweet id)

Tags: mongodb

EDIT: it turns out it's NOT a problem.. pfew! phpMOadmin is not able to display the bigint (probably server apache settings i didn't care).. not mongoDB is unable to save... u.kodingen.com/1fMs5Z  i requested from CLI, and it comes back just fine! sorry mongodb.

---

when i insert tweet to mongodb, it's id e.g. 16906830606 becomes -274549723

our servers are 64bits, I use php mongo driver.

this is the full insert code,

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=worldcup");
$decoded = json_decode($content,true);
  $c = new Mongo("mongodb://x:pass@mng.vps.kodingen.com:27017");
  foreach($decoded['results'] as $tweet) 
  {  
    $tweet['_id'] = $tweet['id'];
    $c->db->tweets->insert($tweet);
  }
```

This is how it saves: http://u.kodingen.com/1fKw6E

If I force it as String,

```
$tweet['_id'] = "" . $tweet['id'];
```

then it's correct: http://u.kodingen.com/1fKy8g

I want to know why this happens, and what else I should be worried about MongoDB while you are at it :) just starting out here..

Comment: i found this in the meantime: http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/fe05de77d93905f4/b8eee19fa475569c?lnk=gst&q=bigint#b8eee19fa475569c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The _id field, that usually stores an [ObjectID](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs), is 12 bytes. A 64-bit integer is 8 bytes. Obviously it has to be converted in some way. As it seems, not in a very good way.

The fact that `the timestamp and counter fields must be stored big endian` could also be in play.

I would consider not using the tweet id as ObjectID since you can't be certain that they don't add a couple of digits to it tomorrow.

Comment: Hi Jonas, thx. it also can't store any big ints in the array either... check in_reply_to_status_id http://u.kodingen.com/1fLW7t i don't want to be checking my array before insertion and cast all integers to strings..

Comment: Hmm, that's a much worse problem!

Comment: it turns out it's NOT a problem.. pfew! phpMOadmin is not able to display the bigint.. not mongoDB is unable to save... http://u.kodingen.com/1fMs5Z i requested from CLI, and it comes back jsut fine!

Comment: Good! It also seems some (all?) JavaScript-implementations has problems with 64 bit integers.

Comment: Best to store a tweet ID as a string. MongoDB stores large numbers as floats - which are subject to rounding errors

Comment: Seems so but I have to admit that I fail to get a definitive answer from the docs. That's a JavaScript inheritance I could have done without!

Answer (score 0):

use ini_set('mongo.native_long', 1); this would store ur integer data as LontInt